# Specific words for cross sections of different orientation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for words to differentiate between different orientations of cross sections. For example, an apple can be cut crosswise:

[image: crosswise]
<sub>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sterappel_dwarsdrsn.jpg)</sub>

Or lengthwise:

[image: lengthwise]
<sub>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Red_delicious,_half.jpg)</sub>

What are the names for the (crosswise) cross section and the (lengthwise) cross sections?

Comment: See also: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57670/what-is-the-difference-between-transverse-section-and-longitudinal-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Difference Between Longitudinal and Transverse Section](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-longitudinal-and-vs-transverse-section/)

> **Longitudinal Section**
>   When a vertical section is cut along the longest axis of an animal or a plant, the longitudinal cut is made. However, it is sometimes defined as the longest section cut in the vertical plane of an animal or a plant. ...
>   **Transverse Section**
>   Transverse section is a cut made in a plane that is made across the body of an animal, a plant, an organ, or a tissue. It is usually referred as the cut made between left and right.

[image: Janel Simpson]

([Janel Simpson](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6996641/))

Comment: Interesting! This conflicts with my bridge engineering experience but is clearly relevant for an apple.

Comment: It's relevant to bridge and every branch of engineering as well.

Comment: Hmmm. For longitudinal section I agree that "cut along the longest axis" works for a longitudinal section of a bridge. The more I look at the definition you've found for transverse section, the more confused I get. A "cut between left and right" for an apple would match OP's "lengthwise", and the terms "left and right" don't really work for a bridge. I think the phrase "across the body" could work for a bridge transverse section, though it's not the clearest wording.

Comment: @AndyT Sections in engineering are more complex -- which is the reason there can be as many axes as one needs: Section X-X' typically. Also, the "axes" do not have to be horizontal or vertical but could be at any angle, as required.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

I propose **plan section** for a section on a horizontal plane, and **sectional elevation** for a section on a vertical plane.

---

According to Wikipedia's [architectural drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_drawing) page:

> A cross section, also simply called a section, represents a vertical plane cut through the object, in the same way as a floor plan is a horizontal section viewed from the top.

This would suggest that **section** is only appropriate for vertical planes. However, **section** is more generally defined as, per [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/section):

> 9. a representation of an object as it would appear if cut by a plane, showing its internal structure.

Further, as a practising bridge engineer, I do not identify with the architectural definition of **section** only being in the vertical plane; I personally would also apply it to a cut in the horizontal plane. So I don't think it suffices for your purposes.

---

In my experience as a bridge engineer I often see the terms **Longitudinal Section** and **Transverse Section**. These are both sections in vertical planes. This works well for a bridge as it has longitudinal and transverse directions. Apples don't, so this doesn't really work for your situation.

---

An **elevation** is a view looking from the side. Per [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elevation?s=t):

> 7. *Architecture.* a drawing or design that represents an object or structure as being projected geometrically on a vertical plane parallel to one of its sides.

I would call a section cut, looking from the side, a **sectional elevation**. This may not be appropriate as it apparently has a slightly more specific definition, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_drawing):

> A sectional elevation is a combination of a cross section, with elevations of other parts of the building seen beyond the section plane.

---

A *plan view* is looking at something from above. Wikipedia (top quote on this answer) likes **floor plan** for a section on a horizontal plane. Obviously an apple doesn't have a floor, but at least there seems to be some agreement on the word **plan**. Per [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plan?s=t) **plan** means:

> 4. Also called plan view. a drawing made to scale to represent the top view or a horizontal section of a structure or a machine, as a floor layout of a building.

In my personal experience the word **plan** on its own does not connotate a section, and means "without a section cut". I would therefore call a section cut, looking from above, a **plan section**.

Comment: Anatomy is another discipline providing relevant terminology: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_plane.