# general purpose synonyms for terms sagittal, coronal and transverse

Tags: synonyms

There are terms which are used for describing cross-sections of human anatomy:

- [sagittal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sagittal) (dividing into left and right halves),
- [coronal](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199687817.001.0001/acref-9780199687817-e-2181?rskey=yTXs3M&result=1) (dividing into front and back halves) and
- [transverse](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199687817.001.0001/acref-9780199687817-e-10284?rskey=CqnRS1&result=2) (situated at right angles to the long axis)

I want to describe a **mechanical** system using similar terms. What are some general purpose synonyms?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400758/specific-words-for-cross-sections-of-different-orientation, but I don't think a duplicate. Still, my bridge-engineering-based answer may be of use.

Comment: @AndyT This is great. Actually this answers two of the 3 terms I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Medial cross sections through the X, Y, and Z axes (presuming these are defined for your model).

Comment: Port/starboard, foreward/aft, above/below......

Comment: Does your mechanism have a front and back? Are any of the views symmetrical with respect to others? You only need one view for a sphere. Two views will deal with a cylinder.

Comment: @Spencer dorsal/ventral as well

Answer (score 1):

***cross-section***:

> something that has been cut in half so that you can see the inside.

Often used in engineering and mechanical drawings for describing inside of a system.

**[Cross-sectional views.](http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me2011/handouts/drawing/blanco-tutorial.html#xsection)**

Comment: indeed, I have three different cross sections, but I don't want to define plains in my pictures.